# How to use eclipse for C and java codes simultaneously

Tags: eclipse

My code base consist of C as well as Java files. Earlier I was using source insight, but now we are into eclipse. I tried to sync my project in eclipse but after making project there I was not able to navigate the full code base, for e.g, I am not able to ctrl +click on java files, though in C file I am able to do. Somehow I am missing something. My eclipse bundle consist of Eclipse Platform, JDT, CDT, EMF, GEF and WTP. Please suggest some solution

Comment: So you have both C and Java sources in a single project?

Comment: Yes As I mentioned I am using both java and C code. Java codes are using JNI files to access C codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure your projects so they contain both C and Java *nature*. So how to create a mixed project?

1. Create standard Java project.
2. In Package Explorer' or Project Explorer's context menu of this project, click **New** -> **Other** and select **Convert to a C/C++ Project**.

This way you can you mix Java and C code. Features like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> should also work.

[image]